# gcc.exe vs cpp.exe vs g++.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, g++

I am using Visual Studio Code for the coding and for C/C++ I uses MinGW. When I click on configure default build task then I can see various options like C/C++:cpp.exe build active file(compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/cpp.exe),C/C++:g++.exe build active file (compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe),C/C++:gcc.exe build active file(compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe),C/C++:g++.exe Task generated by Debugger (compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe) C/C++:gcc.exe Task generated by Debugger (compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe) and two more of g++ & GCC build active file....may anyone explain the need, role & difference among all these. also why there isn't a option of "Task generated by Debugger" for cpp.exe. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- cpp - The C and C++ preprocessor that replaces macros etc. Since you don't have a "Task generated by debugger" for this, it'll most likely be used in the same way for both debug and release builds.
- gcc - The C compiler that is used to compile C programs.
- g++ - The C++ compiler that is used to compile C++ programs

Comment: **it'll most likely be used in the same way for both debug and release builds.** may you elaborate this part...is it not a compiler like u said  its a C/C++ Preprocessor ?and if its not.. then why there is option in dropdown menu of building current file option?

Comment: @Nikhil Yes, it's a preprocessor so if you for example have `#define FOO(x) ((x)*(x))` it will go through the translation unit and replace all uses of `FOO(something)` with `((something)*(something))` etc. This is done _before_ the compilation starts for the translation unit.

Comment: Hi @Ted Lyngmo what I am not getting is according to you cpp is just a pre-processsor and not a compiler but i can see cpp.exe option to build my file with ..means i can build my active file if i select it...building is more sophisticated process than compilation. my question is if it can't even compiler because it is not a compiler then how come i can build my active file with it?

Comment: @Nikhil If you "build" your file with `cpp.exe` you will get a pre-processed file as output. I'm not sure if you can see the result, but if you can, you'll see is that it has included the files you've `#include`d and replaced the macro uses with what they expands too. This becomes the translation unit that the compiler will compile.

Answer (score 2):

guy! I have the same confusion. The cpp.exe produces the exe file and I run it, windows give me the error that it is a 16bit. I think it is the reason.